# The name "context:annotation-config" is not legal for JDOM/XML

Tags: java, spring, jdom-2

How i can write this :

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.generator"/>
```

using jdom2.
i tried by :

> ```
> beans.addContent(new Element("context:annotation-config"));
> beans.addContent(new Element("context:component-scan").setAttribute("base-package","com."+getProjectName()))
> ```

but i had this error:

> The name "context:annotation-config" is not legal for JDOM/XML elements: XML name 'context:annotation-config' cannot contain the character ":".

Comment: Show your namespace declarations.

Comment: I am using JDOM2 to generate spring.xml; 
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"

Comment: `context` is the local name of a XML namespace, that presumably is declared above the section you just showed.  So, you have to get the name space from the document as a JDOM `Namespace` object, and use the `Element(String, Namespace)` constructor.  Something like `new Element("annotation-config", contextNamespace)`.

Comment: See Eric's comment in javadoc [here](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/Element.html). @Eric You should add that as an answer.

Comment: @EricJablow Thanks a lot , the problem is solved

Comment: I'd have added it as an answer, but I didn't have the time to do a full writeup, and I was only going by the Javadoc.  I couldn't test the work. And now @Ravi has posted the answer, so there's no need.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't help but notice the un-accept. Do I need to fix anything?

Comment: @EricJablow, both of us posted nearly at the same time but apparently OP saw your comment first and thanked you as well. Would you like to turn it to an answer? I'll be happy to withdraw mine.

Comment: No.  No need.  I wasn't able to actually test my work.

Answer (score 2):

Create a [Namespace](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/Namespace.html) as

```
Namespace nsContext = Namespace.getNamespace("context", // prefix
       "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"); // URI
```

Then create your `Element` using new [Element (String, Namespace)](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/Element.html#Element%28java.lang.String,%20org.jdom2.Namespace%29)

```
beans.addContent(new Element("annotation-config", nsContext));
```